# Css selector returns blank list

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Hi there I am new to scrapy and web scraping in general and I am having a hard time with trying to scrape from this website: https://www.webuycars.co.za/buy-a-car

My goal is to scrape the car data like the name, price etc from the page

I started with

```
scrapy shell "https://www.webuycars.co.za/buy-a-car"
```

I then did

```
fetch("http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.webuycars.co.za/buy-a-car")
```

I am using splash with scrapy because I have come to the conclusion that the page was created with javascript
I then tried to send some requests but after a certain point in the html of the page I start getting blanks(this is what I assume to be javascript created)
For example

```
response.css("div.col-lg-3.col-md-4.col-sm-6.mt-3").getall()
[]
response.css("div.result-item-title").getall() 
[]
response.css("div.result-item-title").get()
response.css(".result-item-title").getall()
[]
```

Getting the title seems to work but nothing else I have tried works

```
response.css("title::text").get()
'WeBuyCars | Sell Cars For Cash | Free Online Vehicle Valuations'
```

I have been trying to do these requests to make sure I get results before I program the spider and implement it properly into my program.
I set my user agent in the settings file.
I have looked at all the source files to see if there was a json file containing what I needed but there isnt one.
I am not sure what else I can do. I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you probably need to wait for the javascript to actually render those other divs

Comment: Whenever I see JS in the mix I skip the middleman and hit the query.
Open developer tools and click "network" then refresh the page. 

Look for the `json` object called `search`. You have all the data there in a much easier format. 

It's just a `json` `POST` that simply changes the `to:` and `size:` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all data from `API` response

```
import json
import scrapy

class CarsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'car'
    body = {"to":24,"size":24,"type":"All","filter_type":"all","subcategory":None,"q":"","Make":None,"Roadworthy":None,"Auctions":[],"Model":None,"Variant":None,"DealerKey":None,"FuelType":None,"BodyType":None,"Gearbox":None,"AxleConfiguration":None,"Colour":None,"FinanceGrade":None,"Priced_Amount_Gte":0,"Priced_Amount_Lte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Gte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Lte":0,"auctionDate":None,"auctionEndDate":None,"auctionDurationInSeconds":None,"Kilometers_Gte":0,"Kilometers_Lte":0,"Priced_Amount_Sort":"","Bid_Amount_Sort":"","Kilometers_Sort":"","Year_Sort":"","Auction_Date_Sort":"","Auction_Lot_Sort":"","Year":[],"Price_Update_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_In_Progress":""}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search',
            callback=self.parse,
            body=json.dumps(self.body),
            method="POST")

    def parse(self, response):
        response = json.loads(response.body)
       
        for resp in response['data']:
            yield {
                'Title': resp['OnlineDescription']
            }
```

**Output:**

```
{'Title': '2022 Citroen C3 Aircross 1.2T Puretech Sine Auto'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Toyota Hilux 2.4 Gd-6 RB Raider Pick Up Double Cab'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Datsun GO 1.2 MID'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2013 Hyundai i10 1.25 Gls/fluid Auto'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Suzuki S-Presso 1.0 GL+ AMT'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 SYM Symphony JET 14 200'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Nissan Micra 1.2 Active Visia'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2021 Suzuki Super Carry 1.2i Pick Up Single Cab'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Suzuki AN UB 125 (burgman)'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Honda XRL XR 125l'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Toyota Hilux 2.4 Gd-6 RB Raider Pick Up Double Cab'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Land Rover Defender 110 D300 SE X-Dynamic (221 KW)'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Suzuki S-Presso 1.0 GL'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Big Boy TSR 250'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Hyundai Atos/Atoz 1.1 Motion AMT'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Fiat Panda 900t Lounge'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2017 Chevrolet Spark 1.2 Campus/curve 5-Door'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Crosby Adventure Bike 400cc'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Renault Kwid 1.0 Climber 5-Door'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Suzuki Swift 1.2 GLX'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Volkswagen Polo Classic GP 1.4 Comfortline'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Renault Kwid 1.0 Climber 5-Door Auto'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 SYM Crox X-Pro 125'}
2022-05-01 08:15:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Yamaha YZ 450 FX'}
```